# What is a linear / angular deflection in OpenCASCADE's Incremental Mesh?

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh, opencascade

Lately I've been using OpenCASCADE (PythonOCC, to be precise) for some CAD operations, including meshing shapes, and stumbled upon this class: 
[BRepMesh_IncrementalMesh](https://cdn.rawgit.com/tpaviot/pythonocc-core/3ceb6b92/doc/apidoc/0.17.3/OCC.BRepMesh.html?highlight=incrementalmesh#OCC.BRepMesh.BRepMesh_IncrementalMesh).

I didn't find any hints on what the `theLinDeflection` and `theAngDeflection` parameters mean - and would like to know more about this.

I would appreciate any reading materials / hints / explanations on this subject.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These parameters will tell how "close" to the original surface the mesh should be.

In the docs it's described as this:

> Linear deflection limits the distance between a curve and its tessellation, whereas angular deflection limits the angle between subsequent segments in a polyline.

[image: deflections]

Please check OCCT documentation for a [detailed description](https://www.opencascade.com/doc/occt-7.1.0/overview/html/occt_user_guides__modeling_algos.html#occt_modalg_11_2).